# Client side web stack with CoffeeScript, Compass & goodies

Tags: frameworks, twitter-bootstrap, coffeescript, sass, continuous-deployment

Is there such thing as (backend) language agnostic web stack that does something like:

- watches & compiles your CoffeeScript files
- watches & compiles your Compass / Sass files
- supports client side testing like Jasmine
- bundles common tools like Twitter Bootstrap, Font Awesome, ...
- lets you add your own scripts for things like deploying
- lets you add continous-integration features like pre-deploy testing

For instance Rails lets you put your tools together, but I am looking for something that takes care of client side and lets you choose any backend language you want.

**Is there a framework / web stack for this?**

**How do you solve this in your projects?**

(Please vote up answers if you are using / recommend the same approach as the person answering)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tools below comes closest to the features you want:

- [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/)
- [Yeoman](http://yeoman.io/)
- [Brunch](http://brunch.io/)

Yeoman uses Grunt, which is highly adaptable / extensible. So I would choose **Yeoman** or **Grunt**, if I were you. They support the features you want, and if not out of the box, they have plugins which do.

Comment: Wow, I wish I knew about Grunt & Yeoman earlier! Those tasks will come handy, thanks!